# Ignoring values after split and duplicating only part of a cell in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a new field that contains data from a pre-existing field which has been formatted.  If a cell in the existing field contains the following data (including newline characters):

```
╔══════════════════════════╗
║       ExistingField      ║
╠══════════════════════════╣
║ App: Some Name           ║
║ App: Another Name        ║
║ App: A Different Name    ║
║ Supplier: Supplier Name  ║
╚══════════════════════════╝
```

Then the new field should look as follows:

```
╔═════════════════════════╦══════════════════╗
║      ExistingField      ║ NewField         ║
╠═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ App: Some Name          ║ Some Name        ║
║ App: Another Name       ║                  ║
║ App: A Different Name   ║                  ║
║ Supplier: Supplier Name ║                  ║
╠═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ App: Some Name          ║ Another Name     ║
║ App: Another Name       ║                  ║
║ App: A Different Name   ║                  ║
║ Supplier: Supplier Name ║                  ║
╠═════════════════════════╬══════════════════╣
║ App: Some Name          ║ A Different Name ║
║ App: Another Name       ║                  ║
║ App: Different Name     ║                  ║
║ Supplier: Supplier Name ║                  ║
╚═════════════════════════╩══════════════════╝
```

What this is doing is looking at each value after `App:` such as `Some Name`.  For each of those values existing in a cell, the record is duplicated and each value is stored in a new record in the `NewField` field.  This table has no primary key and there can be any number of `App:` and `Supplier:` combinations in a cell under the `ExistingField`.

---

I have gotten to the point where my code will split a cell on newline and duplicate records, however it is not yet ignoring `Supplier:` and it is populating the `NewField` with the entire `App: Some Name` instead of only `Some Name`.  How could I achieve the intended result?

Here is my code so far:

```
Public Sub CreateNameField(tableName As String)

    Dim db As DAO.Database

    Set db = CurrentDb

    ' Create NewField field '
    Dim strDdl As String
    strDdl = "ALTER TABLE [" & tableName & "] ADD COLUMN NewField TEXT(255);"

    Debug.Print strDdl
    CurrentProject.Connection.Execute strDdl

    ' Select all fields that have a ExistingField and are unprocessed (NewField is Null) '
    strSQL = "SELECT *, NewField " & _
             " FROM [" & tableName & _
             "] WHERE ([ExistingField] Is Not Null) AND ([NewField] Is Null)"

    Set rsADD = db.OpenRecordset(tableName, dbOpenDynaset, dbAppendOnly)

    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

    With rs
        While Not .EOF

            ' Split field on newline '
            varData = Split(rs![ExistingField], vbCrLf)

            ' Update First Record '
            ' Ensure that varData contains at least one value '
            If UBound(varData) > -1 Then
                .Edit
                !NewField = Trim(varData(0)) ' Remove spaces before writing new fields '
                .Update
            End If

            ' Add records with same first field '
            ' and new fields for remaining data at end of string '
            For i = 1 To UBound(varData)
                rsADD.AddNew
                For Each fld In rsADD.Fields
                    If fld.Name <> "NewField" Then
                        ' Copy all fields except "NewField" '
                        rsADD(fld.Name) = rs(fld.Name)
                    End If
                Next fld
                ' NewField is set separately '
                rsADD!NewField = Trim(varData(i)) ' Remove spaces before writing new fields '
                rsADD.Update
            Next i

            .MoveNext
        Wend

        .Close
        rsADD.Close

    End With

    Set rsADD = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing
    db.Close
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to test each element in the array from Split():

```
Dim newVal
If varData(i) Like "App: *" Then
    newVal = Replace(varData(i),"App: ", "")
    'add the new record using newVal
End if
```